# Alternando entre páginas [Page Class] numa aplicação

Tags: c#, wpf, memória

Estou a pesquisar exemplos de navegação entre páginas numa aplicação desktop.
Vamos supor que a navegação é feita a partir de um ListBox sempre visível na Ui.
A maior parte dos exemplos faz algo do género do seguinte para mudar para uma determinada página:

```
private void myListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int index = myListBox.SelectedIndex;
    switch(index+1)
    {
        case 1:
            mainFrame.Content = new Page1();
            break;
        case 2:
            mainFrame.Content = new Page2();
            break;
        case 3:
            mainFrame.Content = new Page3();
            break;
    }
}
```

A minha dúvida neste caso é quanto à gestão de memória.
Este tipo de abordagem não vai criar um número indeterminado de instâncias das várias página invocada?
Pergunto isto porque, ativando a barra de navegação, encontro as diferentes instâncias da mesma classe.
Não será mais correto algo assim?

```
private void myListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int index = myListBox.SelectedIndex;
    switch(index+1)
    {
        case 0: mainFrame.Content = p0;
            break;
        case 1:
            mainFrame.Content = p1;
            break;
        case 2:
            mainFrame.Content = p2;
            break;
        case 3:
            mainFrame.Content = p3;
            break;
    }
}
Page0 p0 = new Page0();
Page1 p1 = new Page1();
Page2 p2 = new Page2();
Page3 p3 = new Page3();
```

Answer (score 0):

Depende de sua aplicação:

Se você possui um sistema com poucas páginas, carrega-las inicialmente, na segunda opção pode ser o ideal;

Mas na primeira além de "limpar" a página, ela será carregada on-demand, e para um sistema de muitas páginas seria o melhor carregar uma instancia por vez.